# Characterization of semiprime ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am solving someone exercises of the book Lecture on Rings and Modules (LAMBEK) and on page 62, section 3.3, there is the follow exercise.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$. Every large ideal of $R$ is dense if, and only if $R$ is semiprime.

I proved ($\Leftarrow$), but I have no idea to prove ($\Rightarrow$).

**Definition:** Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$. An ideal $I$ is called **large** if $I\cap J\neq 0$, for every nonzero ideal $J$; $I$ is called **dense** if, for all $r\in R$, $rI=0$ implies $r=0$; $R$ is called **semiprime** if $0$ is the only nilpotent element.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Mathphile, do you realize that semiprime *rings* have nothing to do with semiprime *numbers*? All the ring theory questions where you've added the "semiprime" tag – someone is going to have to go remove that inappropriate tag. You have done a lot of damage to this website, in a short period of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $R$ is not semiprime. If $x \neq 0$ is a nilpotent element of $R$, its annihilator

$I := \lbrace r \in R: rx=0 \rbrace$

is an ideal which violates the hypothesis.

Proof: $I$ is large, for if there were a non-zero ideal $J$ with $I \cap J = 0$, the definition of $I$ would imply that each non-zero $y \in J$ satisfies $xy \neq 0$. Since $xy \in J$, further $x^2y \in J \setminus \lbrace 0\rbrace$. Inductively, $x^ny \neq 0$ for all $n$, which contradicts $x$ being nilpotent.

But $I$ is not dense since $xI = 0$ but $x \neq 0$.

Comment: Your solution is excellent! Thanks a lot for the help.